# Android support libraries folders do not have newer versions

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-support-library

I have dug into the Android SDK path folders, specifically:

> extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7
>
> extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4

And saw the folders shown in the following images for appcompat-v7 and support-v4 respectively:
[image: appcompat-v7]
[image: support-v4]

There are some questions:

1. Is this the path when Gradle starts to download support libraries and places their folders?
2. In some of my projects I've used **appcompat-v7:27.0.2** which does not exist in these folders, but there wasn't any problem in the project build process.
3. I have used **support-v4:27.0.2** in a project but it gives the following error:

> failed to resolve support-v4

When I change support-v4 to one of the revision (i.e 25.3.0) in extras folder there isn't any error and I have a successful build. If there isn't any 27.0.2 folder so what is the difference between appcompat-v7 and support-v4 with the same revision number?